# Apply style in textarea Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm new to Angularjs & Angular Material, I'm doing a validation inside a textarea like this:

```
<md-content flex layout="column">
<label flex>Comments</label>
<textarea required="" placeholder="Los comentarios son necesarios." cols='23' rows='3' flex ng-model="vm.blog_comments">{{vm.blog_comments}}</textarea>
                  <style>
                        textarea.ng-invalid {
                        background-color:pink;
                        }
                        textarea.ng-valid {
                        background-color:transparent;
                        }
                   </style>
            </md-content>
```

This works but I need the style to be applied inside a css file. Could you help me?

Comment: Just put the stuff between `<style></style>` in an external stylesheet... what do you need help with exactly?

Comment: Don't really see the problem here. What issue are you facing?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I need the style to be applied in my css file not inside my html file, but I do not know how to do it

Comment: a simple google search on how to attatch external css file would do the trick don't you think?

Comment: Thank you so much Sagar, will look for.

Comment: Oh! i forgot to thank Michael Coker. Thanks M.C.